Is Elisa the person who created Mira in World's End Harem?
There's a recollection of someone with purple hair outside the glass tank saying something when Mira was being created. Was the person Elisa? If not, who's she? Did Elisa know of the creating of Mira?

Regarding the one who created Mira, in volume 11, chapters 74-76,

 UW's Japanese branch has an underground research facility, including a cloning facility. They were also monitoring Mira's growth without Elisa's involvement.

As for the purple-hair someone, in volume 11, chapters 75-76,

 Elisa was the one who was outside the glass tank watching Mira, her clone created as a mating partner for Reito.

The reason is revealed in volume 11, chapter 74, that

 Elisa cannot bear a child due to a disease, thus she is not suitable as a mating partner for Reito.


I admit I only read the manga, so I don't know how far the anime adapted the manga. This answer is based near the end of the manga's first "season".
